# Mininet pingall fails

Tags: mininet, openflow, vlan

I am to Mininet and I am trying to set up a VLAN. It has four host h1, h2, h3, and h4 connected to one switch. I want h1 and h3 on VLAN 100 and h2 and h4 on VLAN 200. I am having trouble with writing the code under runExperiment. I updated my code where I can manually ping h1 to h3 successfully and h2 to h4 successfully. However, when it comes to the pingall command, I don't get any ping connectivity.
[image: Output]

I also included my [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SkdXXTY4uBoBupWoUBlEBsi2x1g811oA/view?usp=sharing) of the Mininet topology.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What I needed to do was to create a new VLAN interface and map the newly created interface to the host. For example, my code for host 1 looks like this.

```
h1.cmd("vconfig add h1-eth0 100")   

newName = 'h1-eth0.100'
intf = h1.defaultIntf()
intf.name = newName
h1.nameToIntf[newName] = intf
```

More information that might be helpful to look at is the github page
[link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/vlanhost.py)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the controller: ryu-manager ryu.app.simple_switch_13